# react-native - Fit Image in containing View, not the whole screen size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox, react-native

I'm trying to fit images in their containing views so that I can have a seamless grid of images. The problem is that `resizeMode='contain'` seems to fit to the width of the screen or at least some higher level container, I need the images to fit to the size of each list item.

Here's a very ugly example of the styles and resulting grid:

The styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  },

  item: {
    flex: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    position: 'relative',
    margin: 10
  },

  image: {
    flex: 1
  }
})
```

The layout:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
  activeOpacity={ 0.75 }
  style={ styles.item }
>
  <Image
    style={ styles.image }
    resizeMode='contain'
    source={ temp }
  /> 
</TouchableOpacity>
```

The result (with `resizeMode='contain'`):

[image]

The result (with `resizeMode='cover'`):

[image]

As you can see, the `cover`ed images are very big and are as wide as the whole screen and don't fit the immediately containing view.

**Update 1:**

I was able to achieve a result close to what I'm looking for by applying a scale transform to the image and shrinking it from the center:

The transform:

```
transform: [{ scale: 0.55 }]
```

The resulting layout (without margins or paddings):
[image]

Comment: Can you possible give an example image of how you would like them to look or close to it? Thanks.

Comment: Hey @NaderDabit I'll update with an example right now.

Comment: Are all of the images going to be square?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I could not get the example working using the `resizeMode` properties of `Image`, but because the images will all be square there is a way to do it using the Dimensions of the window along with flexbox.

Set `flexDirection: 'row'`, and `flexWrap: 'wrap'`, then they will all line up as long as they are all the same dimensions.

I set it up [here](https://snack.expo.io/HkbZNqjeZ)

https://snack.expo.io/HkbZNqjeZ

```
"use strict";

var React = require("react-native");
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView
} = React;

var deviceWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
var temp = "http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/close-up-angry-chihuahua-growling-2-years-old-15126199.jpg";
var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var images = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      images.push(
        <TouchableOpacity key={i} activeOpacity={0.75} style={styles.item}>
          <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: temp }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }

    return (
      <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {images}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nader, I used your solution and it worked perfectly. I was hoping for something that will use the builtin flexbox support but this is doing what I need.

Answer (score 128):

If you know the aspect ratio for example, if your image is square you can set either the `height` or the `width` to fill the container and get the other to be set by the `aspectRatio` property

Here is the style if you want the `height` be set automatically:

```
{
    width: '100%',
    height: undefined,
    aspectRatio: 1,
}
```

Note: `height` must be `undefined`

Edit (Based on @rob-art's comment):
If your image is a different aspect ratio than the one you want to set in the style you can use `resizeMode` to control how the image should be displayed. Use `resizeMode:'contain'` to ensure your image is not cropped.
See [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode) for more details

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? It seemed to work for me. If there is something I need to fix, please comment

Comment: I had to add resizeMode: 'contain' to make it work. If not the default cover mode crop the image.

Answer (score 59):

Set the dimensions to the **View** and make sure your **Image** is styled with height and width set to **'undefined'** like the example below :

```
    <View style={{width: 10, height:10 }} >
      <Image style= {{flex:1 , width: undefined, height: undefined}}    
       source={require('../yourfolder/yourimage')}
        />
    </View>
```

This will make sure your image scales and fits perfectly into your view.

Comment: this worked forme, tho can undefined cause any issues?

Answer (score 46):

Anyone over here who wants his image to fit in full screen without any crop (in both portrait and landscape mode), use this:

```
image: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
},
```

Answer (score 12):

Simply You need to pass resizeMode like this to fit in your image in containing view

```
<Image style={styles.imageStyle} resizeMode={'cover'} source={item.image}/>

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  imageStyle: {
      alignSelf: 'center',
      height:'100%', 
      width:'100%'
    },]
})
```

Answer (score 6):

This is working for me,

```
<Image style={styles.imageStyle} resizeMode="cover" source={imageSource} />

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageStyle: {
    width: undefined,
    height: '100%',
    aspectRatio: 1,
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I think it's because you didn't specify the width and height for the `item`.

If you only want to have 2 images in a row, you can try something like this instead of using flex:

```
item: {
    width: '50%',
    height: '100%',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    position: 'relative',
    margin: 10,
},
```

This works for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "Resize Matters" library which always fix the image scaling.

```
import { scale, verticalScale } from 'react-native-size-matters';

export const Component = props =>
    <Image style={{
        width: scale(30),
        height: verticalScale(50)
    }}/>;
```

Here you will be happy: https://github.com/nirsky/react-native-size-matters

Answer (score 0):

the image has a property named Style ( like most of the react-native Compponents)
 and for Image's Styles, there is a property named resizeMode that takes values like:
contain,cover,stretch,center,repeat

most of the time if you use center it will work for you